# How work method injection in Dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

For example I have next code

```
public class Class {

   @Inject
   public void classMethod(SomeObject object) {
   //something
   }
}
```

Then I invoke classMethod method got SomeObject instance from graph. But how to run the method, because at the moment I dont have have method arg.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this myself, but my guess is that methods annotated with `@Inject` are designed to be called by Dagger only. Example:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  SomeObject someObject;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    ((InjectorActivity) getActivity()).component().inject(this);
  }

  @Inject
  public void injectSomeObject(SomeObject someObject) {
    this.someObject = someObject;
  }
}
```

Would be interested to know if it's indeed working like this.

Comment: How would that behave for subclasses of MyFragment that may override injectSomeObject ? Is Dagger gonna call both the subclass and superclass method ?? @Egor